# Gaussian elimination or compute determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

One of my homework problems asks  whether the set S = {(2, -1, 2), (1, 0, 3), (3, -2, 1)} is linearly independent.

My book lists out a bunch of steps for problems similar to this, which basically say that I should first form the following system of equations:

2c1 + c2 + 3c3 = 0

-c1 - 2c3 = 0

2c1 + 3c2 + c3 = 0

Then form the augmented matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3&0\\-1&0&-2&0\\2&3&1&0\end{bmatrix}
And then reduce this using Gaussian elimination in order to tell whether the system has a unique solution.

My question is, couldn't I just form the *coefficient* matrix (rather than the augmented matrix), find its determinant, and if it's nonzero conclude that the system has only the trivial solution and is linearly independent?

Or do I really need to use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: You can use both methods because the matrix is square. However, it is better to ask your professor - maybe the goal of the exercise is to practice Gaussian elimination?

Comment: The determinant suffices to answer the question in the case of a square matrix. But even then, the Gaussian elimination gives you more information. In the case where they are _not_ independent, it allows you to find the coefficients of a linear combination of the columns that equals to the zero vector.

Comment: Further to quasi's remark, if you write down the 3 by 3 matrix with rows the vectors in S, then do Gaussian elimination, a row of zeros will imply dependence. Further, the remaining none zero rows, written as columns, will form a basis of S.